# How to chain transitions/animation in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, animation

### Target

[image]

On click "Open menu" button:

1. Dim overlay appearing with fade-in animation

[image]

2. Once dim overlay animation done, from the top, dim overlay is appearing with the sliding animation from the top to bottom:

[image]

### Solution attempt and problem

```
<template lang="pug">
  transition(name="fade")
    .DrawerMenu-DimUnderlay(v-if="displayFlag")
      .DrawerMenu-Body Drawer menu
</template>
```

Before slide down the `.DrawerMenu-Body`, `.DrawerMenu-DimUnderlay` must be mounted and rendered.
I don't know how to implement it.

[image]

[Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-tereshkova-fcvyu?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using CSS Animations and Vue Transition.

First, separate your overlay and content into different transitions:

```html
<template lang="pug">
  div
    transition(name="overlay")
      .DrawerMenu-Overlay(v-if="displayFlag")
    transition(name="content")
      .DrawerMenu-Body(v-if="displayFlag") Drawer menu
</template>
```

Then define your animations:

```css
.DrawerMenu {
  &-Overlay {
    ...
    display: none;
  }
  ...
}

.overlay-enter-active {
  display: block;
  animation: fade-in-and-slide-down 2s;
}

.content-enter-active {
  animation: wait-and-fade-in 3s;
}

.content-leave-active {
  animation: fade-out 1s;
}

@keyframes fade-in-and-slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes wait-and-fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Example in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-carson-ipmdp?file=/src/components/DrawerMenu.vue).

Another solution is using JavaScript animation library (such as [animejs](https://animejs.com/)) combine with [Vue Transition Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-Hooks). I would prefer this solution for a complex animation.

```html
<template lang="pug">
  transition(@enter='enter' @leave='leave')
    div(v-if='displayFlag')
      .DrawerMenu-Overlay(ref='overlay')
      .DrawerMenu-Body(ref='content' @click="displayFlag = false") Drawer menu
</template>
```

```js
import anime from "animejs";
...
  methods: {
    enter(el, done) {
      anime
        .timeline({
          easing: "linear",
          duration: 1000,
          complete: done
        })
        .add({
          targets: this.$refs.overlay,
          opacity: [0, 1]
        })
        .add({
          targets: this.$refs.overlay,
          translateY: "100%"
        })
        .add({
          targets: this.$refs.content,
          opacity: [0, 1]
        });
    },
    leave(el, done) {
      anime({
        targets: el,
        duration: 2000,
        opacity: 0,
        complete: done
      });
    },
    ...
  }
...
```

> You can also use without `transition` component but you have to handle v-if variable by yourself.

Example in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-khayyam-icvby?file=/src/components/DrawerMenu.vue).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So, the separating into 2 layers is necessary condition?

Comment: Umm It's not necessary but it make things easier. For a single transition example see https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-montalcini-ehk3z?file=/src/components/DrawerMenu.vue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are 2 questions here, but for your last question, I would say that is because that ref component does not have a property `display`.

It does however, have a function `display()`

Therefore, change your button click to this:

```
<button @click="$refs.drawerMenu.display()">Open menu</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I updated the fiddle. So, the handler wants the function's return value (void in this case), no the functional expression?